# Leaky transistor --?

Tags: transistors

I'm using a transistor (2n2222) as a switch to enable and disable a 2.5 MHz clock signal (purple in the 'scope screen shot), and it appears that output is attenuated when the base is low, but I'm curious why the emitter still has a replica of the input when the base is low.  I'd figure the output / emitter should be 0, or ground, when the base is low.  What am I overlooking, here?  "Pin PTA27" is coming from a µController.  I checked the output of PTA27, and it's definitely 0 except for the brief time it's set high.

[image: Oscilloscope image showing clock (purple) and the output at the emitter (yellow)]
[image: Schematic of the circuit that produces the 'scope screenshot]

Comment: Transistors aren’t perfect switches - they have leakage and capacitance. Read the datasheet of the transistor and calculate how these effects might create what you observe.

Comment: What is the source impedance of the clock? Why can't you use a digital buffer with an enable?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, the clock is: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2045.  And I didn't use a digital buffer, because I don't know what it is: I'm not a professional EE.  I'm trying to mimic the output to a coil in a cochlear implant, which seems to use a 2.5 MHz signal for various lengths of time.  My first-pass approach was to "gate" the clock signal through a transistor.

Comment: You can see more about the signal and what it's trying to do at https://os-ci.org/images/mission.png .

Comment: Here's a data sheet for a [NAND gate](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g00-ep.pdf?ts=1649686701529) that'll work much better.  A 2N2222 is hideously slow by today's standards, part of that "slow" is letting signal leak through when it should be off.

Comment: @TimWescott, I'll give that a shot and see how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @TimWescott, here's a shot of the waveform after implementing the NAND gate.  Much nicer!  Thanks! https://os-ci.org/images/nandGateOutput.png

Answer (score 1):

Your 10 kΩ on the emitters quite large, and the transistor's C-E capacitance (perhaps 2 pF ?) will easily couple the 2.5 MHz signal from the collector to the emitter node via that capacitance. In addition, your scope probe adds perhaps 10-20 pF of capacitance at the emitter.

You can see that this is happening because a) the square wave on the collector is attenuated (by C-E capacitance divided by scope capacitance; perhaps a factor of 10 ?) to make the sharp sides on the emitter waveform. The sloping tops show the signal is trying to relax towards 0 V -- perhaps with a time constant of about 2 cycles (1 us). This is the product of the emitter resistor and the total capacitance at the emitter.

Comment: Ah. In the morning, I'll test it with a different resistor.  I went with 10k because I wanted to limit current, and it was handy at the time.  Thanks!

Comment: I grabbed a handy 220 Ω and tried it instead of the 10 K Ω, and it's clearly a better pattern.  You can still see some artifacts of the clock signal, but they're nowhere near as bad.  I expect a 100 Ω resistor would further diminish the artifacts.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need ANY resistor in the emitter if the 2.5 MHz signal can be grounded -- i.e. comes from some source with a resistance.